# Share SCSS variables across different Projects/Sites

Tags: css, sass

I was wondering if it's possible to share my SASS variables between different projects from a central static server/location.

For example:

```
[Vars file on static server]
    |                  |
{Project 1     |  {Project 2
load vars then |  load the same
compile CSS}   |  vars and compile CSS}
```

The layout of project 2 is different but it has the same colours. That's why I want to share the vars.

Thanks for any help/suggestions!

Comment: What about import relative path to file @import "../Above/Project1/colors";

Comment: @Bernhard Relative wouldn't work because the two projects are on different servers/domains. Thanks for your input though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@import` statement in SASS does not have the capability to import remote http files, it would treat an http import as a simple css import instead. **([SASS `@import` documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import))**
However, there is a project on GitHub called **[remote-sass](https://github.com/joeellis/remote-sass)** which does what you ask.

> RemoteSass is a small gem that allows Sass to import remote sass/scss
>   stylsheets over HTTP/S. With this, you can set up a central server to
>   serve your stylesheet assets and share css among your many
>   applications.

Comment: That looks great. Any chance to get this version of the lib in JS though NPM ... in 2024? :-D